# What is the best way to apply linear gradient on an image?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the image be slightly darker at the bottom with a linear gradient but I can't get it to work. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I tried to use `::after` in css as I've seen on other sites, I tried using IDs, I tried using `background-image`` straight in css but I can't seem to get it to work. I also tried making the gradient affect only the image, the whole section, the entire article but still it does not work. I don't know what else to try.

```css
.Series {
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-270deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
}
```

```html
<section id="Series">
  <img class="imgshadow" src="cara2.jpg" width="240">
  <div class="texto1">text</div>
  <h1 class="subtext1">text</h1>
</section>
```

Comment: `.Series` selects all elements with the `class` of `Series`. You're using an ID, `<section id="Series">`. Try `#Series`? You also have a stray `</span>`

Comment: beside the id/class mistake, your gradient is white , if your main background is also white, then there is nothing to see ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider [`mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) :

> The `mix-blend-mode` CSS property sets how an element's content should blend with the content of the element's parent and the element's background.

Also, fix your selector from class `.` to id `#`.

```css
#Series {
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-270deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
}

img {
  mix-blend-mode: overlay
}

body {
  background: purple
}
```

```html
<section id="Series">
  <img class="imgshadow" src="http://dummyimage.com/200/0df" width="240">
  <div class="texto1">text</div>
  <h1 class="subtext1">text</h1>
</section>
```

Comment: I see the gradient, but its appearing behind the image. How can I change it so that it appears over the image?

Comment: @dominique120 i updated the snippet with mix-blend-mode for the image , is it what you expect ?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to select elements with `class` "Series". The HTML element it self has an `id` of "Series", so the gradient can't actually get to this element.

Replace `.Series` with `#Series`, or `id="Series"` with `class="Series"`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for your question is you were using white color as the gradient colour so i have changed just your color code to fix the issue. Here is the link for the fiddle fix
[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/SHABU89/vq9kbLgs/)

```
<section id="Series">
  <img class="imgshadow" src="https://content.fortune.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/0ahuznqcmgooafcr7vfc1p9oc9r45f84l1uj4mit2smcopfaxr0gatttneqwlqk-dnbb_eyklizhxhv1dgnj0c.jpg" width="240">
  <div class="texto1">text</div>
  <h1 class="subtext1">text</h1>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
#Series {
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image:  -webkit-linear-gradient(-270deg, rgba(23, 22, 22, 0.39), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradien(-270deg, rgba(23, 22, 22, 0.39), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  position:relative;
 }
 .texto1{
   position:absolute;
   z-index:99999;
   top:0px;
 }
  .imgshadow{
   mix-blend-mode: overlay
 }
 .subtext1{
     position:absolute;
   z-index:99999;
   top:10px; 
 }
```

Comment: I see the gradient but how do I make it appear in front of the image? Its appearing behind it so its not visible. Thanks

Comment: @dominique120 I have updated the codes and also fiddle please check it.

Answer (score -1):

The ID selector for css is '#' and not '.';

Try using #Series {
    ...
}